# How do I load all csv files in a subfolder in python into lists and arrays named after the filenames?

Tags: python, windows, csv, filesystems

I've stripped out the full path.
But I've written this:

```py
def ImportCSVs(chatty = False):
    directory = os.path.join("c:\\", "data")
    files = pathlib.Path(directory)
    for file in files.iterdir():
        if file.is_file():
            filename, fileextention = os.path.splitext(file.name)
            if str(fileextention) == ".csv":
                f = open(file, 'r')
                if "Matrix" in str(pathlib.Path(filename).stem):
                    if chatty == True:
                        print("Loading Array:" + filename)
                    filename.stem = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=","))
                else:
                    if chatty == True:
                        print("Loading List:" + filename)
                    filename.stem = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=","))
                file.close()
        else:
            if chatty == True:
                print("Not Loaded:" + file)
```

I figure the Array part is wrong and will take some doing. But running ImportCSVs right now

returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 16, in ImportCSVs
TypeError: 'WindowsPath' object is not iterable
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this error?

I've rewritten the file/filename portions a half-dozen times to no avail.

Comment: Did you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58572142/typeerror-argument-of-type-windowspath-is-not-iterable) - see accepted answer

Comment: I did! Maybe I just don't know where to place the str() commands or something, but I was unable to get that to work.